# Show footer at the bottom of the page even if there is not enough content

Tags: html, css

I tried to display the footer at the bottom of the page even if there is no content and it seems to work. However, you have to scroll to see the footer. It’s right after you scroll and not on the bottom of the page right away. I can’t figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
<body>
    <div id="root">
        <div class="app">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="nav">
                    <div>
                        <header class="header">
                            <div>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Title</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>About</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </header>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footerWrap">
                <div>
                    <footer>
                        <div class="copyright">
                            <div class="text">© 2018 Footer</div>
                        </div>
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

styles:

```
html, body, #root, .app {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
.footerWrap {
    background-color: green;
    padding-top: 15px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: your `min-height` is missing a value

Comment: thanks @Alec, I updated the question. the min-height is 100%. I made a typo when asking question

Comment: Are you wanting your footer to appear at bottom of the page, no matter if there is content or not? I'm not quite understanding your question. Although, it seems footers should always be relative on page, and appear at bottom of the content, appearing at the bottom of "page" is a bit odd because who decides what is the bottom of the page? And this would not really look good on a page without a lot of content.

Comment: @Alec, I want the footer to appear at the bottom of page if there is not enough content while showing the footer after the content if there is enough content to fill the page.

Itried to remove padding-bottom: 100px;
and it solved the problem but if there is content, it will be on top of footer component. not sure how to make it both work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should make the footer appear always at the bottom of the page. We make the footer wrapper have `position: absolute` and use `bottom: 0` to push it to the bottom. `left: 0` removes the horizontal scrollbar.

```css
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.footerWrap {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="footerWrap">Footer Here</div>
</html>
```

I stripped out all the excess divs to make it easier to read.

Comment: When content is not full, it works great but once there is more content it breaks over the footer. Is it possible to keep footer below the content

example when content passes the footer (might have to resize preview): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZRzZrr

Comment: @stevew1 check the answer now, I updated the code pen and styles. Working in codepen

Comment: It looks like I jumped the gun. It does not work when there is no content, the footer collapses to the top.
ex: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jKWmpV

Comment: @stevew1 test it now, sorry! i switched the html and body tag, but the html tag needs the min height to be 100%

Comment: Did something similar and it works. `position: relative` in `<html>` tag, `min-height: 100vh` in `<body>` tag, `position: absolute; width: 100%; bottom: 0;` in `<footer>` tag.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the flex layout method.

```html
<body class="Site">
   <header>...</header>
   <main class="Site-content">...</main>
   <footer>...</footer>
</body>
```

```css
.Site {
   display: flex;
   min-height: 100vh;
   flex-direction: column;
}

.Site-content {
   flex: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the height of the window (say w) and height of your footer (say f ). Then set minimum height of your content box to (w-f). That way footer will always appear at bottom if there is no content and will appear after content if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<body>
  <div id="root">
    <div class="app">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="nav">
          <div>
            <header class="header">
              <div>
                <ul>
                  <li>Title</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div>
                <ul>
                  <li>About</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </header>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <div>
          <footer>
            <div class="copyright">
              <div class="text">© 2018 Footer</div>
            </div>
          </footer>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<style>
*{ list-style: none; color: #fff; padding: 0; margin: 0; } .header{ background-color: #333; height: 70px; width: 100vw; display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; justify-content: center; } .footer{ position: absolute; bottom: 0; height:
70px; width: 100vw; background-color:#333; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; }

</style>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).